# Do SharePoint 2016 provides Deduplication feature?

Tags: 2016, document-archiving

Do SharePoint 2016 provides Deduplication feature for duplicated documents not save in one content database, like other document archiving products provides? Do shredded storage feature provides Dedeuplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. SP contains Shredded Storage meaning that when versioning is enabled in document libraries, only changes are stored for subsequent versions of a document instead of storing full copies of each version.